# How to access link of a list using an index or similar

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to learn some selenium webdriver using C#.

**My problem:**
I wan't to access a list using an index.

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="pageNavigation">    
  <li><a href="/users/dashboard">&#187; Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="/users">&#187; Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="/accounts/settings">&#187; Settings</a></li>
```

In **WatiN** i did this,

```
ie.List(Find.ByClass("pageNavigation")).ListItem(Find.ByIndex(2)).Links[0].Click();
```

how can Selenium do the same?

And I'm sorrry if this question is a bit basic.

Comment: I solved this by using XPath.
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='windowLogin']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).Click();

If there's a better way of solving this please post :)

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath looks way too complicated. Btw, why do you want to access index? Try something like this or use By.partialText if you want

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Profile"));
link.click();
```

Second longer route would be

```
 List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.pageNavigation>li>a"));
                for(WebElement link:links){
                    String linkText = link.getText();
                    if(linkText.equals("oneIwanted")){
                        //do stuff
                        //get index and all
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the reason i don't want to use a text identifier is that the text is a simple resource which can be changed at any point(By webmasters) while the structure behind the text is much more static.

But the last example might be useful for me in another situation so thanks for that :)

Comment: If developers add a link between two links or remove a link from the page, your indices will be off and your tests will break. In such a situation if you had used text then indices don't really matter. I still think that using text inside your code is more manageable than maintaining indices. If you think the text is most likely change you can always use partial text too..This has been mostly my experience though, perhaps your case is different.

Comment: But this is still only if the change is within the id='windowLogin' right? From what I understand the rest of the page can change as much as they like as long as the window login area remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Find CSS Selectors

css=.pageNavigation > a[href*='dashboard']

css=.pageNavigation > a[href='/users']

css=.pageNavigation > a[href*='settings']

Then C# API can be used to Perform Operations using above Locators.